# How to find a some text that cloud have lots of different stuff in it in a string in js

Tags: javascript, replace

I am building website where people can learn to code. I know how the courses are going to be stored, but I need one more thing, Custom Error messages. I want it so the creator of the course can put in some conman error you might make so people who just started not error messages they don't understand. I am trying to make a feature for it so you can type /*/ in the errors and that can mean anything. Let's say you are meant to type: `console.log('hi')`, but they type: `console.log(hi)` instead. I want to tell them that they put in the wrong value, not a big error message or just you got something wrong. Basically, I just want to find text that can have anything inside it in a place in a string. How would I do that?

Comment: There is no easy, auto-magic way to do that. Even your IDE struggles with this kind of stuff. The only feasible option is, to anticipate the most common errors, and catch them using a list of regex/patterns with associated custom error messages.
you can also collect "unmatched" errors/mistakes and use this list to fine-tune in production. (e.g. a new user types `console_log("hi")` => you get an email "unrecognized mistake made: ... => you add a new pattern with a new error message to the algorithm

Comment: I think I might use this. Thank @MarianTheisen

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand your requirement that you want to implement a custom editor which instantaneously prompt the user if there is anything wrong in sense of syntax error. For this you must have to develop a code parser using compiler construction algorithms. You may look for DFA OR NFA for much better understanding of developing a custom code parser. Well, We all know a quote

> Don't re-invent the wheel

That's means instead of wasting time and energy on implementing custom parser for end users, you can use the third party open source tools that can be easily embed in your site with all features ready to use. Further you may be interested in following urls.

https://codemirror.net/1/story.html
https://gist.github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/a6c1535ffca1b4056a923a04299e60dc

Comment: I don't need the highlighting but thanks for the link when code that in. The github link doesn't seem to work. I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accepting' of undefined`. is there a way to fix that?